# Difference between calling tomcat shutdown script and killing process

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

On our linux boxes, we have multiple users who run tomcat.

Currently we are using process kill commands to kill the respective user's tomcat , instead of using shutdown.sh

Are there any downsides of using this approach ?

Answer (score 8):

It depends on what [`kill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) signal you are using:

- If you use `TERM` (the numeric equivalent is `kill -15`), theoretically you are letting the `java` process signal its children and exit in a correct way.
- If you use `KILL` (`kill -9`), [you don't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process), and [you left all sorts of temporary files,
  sockets](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter), etc... behind.

That said, `tomcat` has its own mechanism to shutdown properly, namely an RMI call which you should be using, either directly or by using your operating system's interface: `service`, `start`, `systemctl` or any other.

If you can't do that for whatever reason, you could use some help from a wrapper like [`tanukiwrapper`](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/) or [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/), which also has a web frontend.

Comment: What difference would be there if we use kill -15 and shutdown script ?

Comment: The answer is above, you need to check what the shutdown script does (hint: it does not `kill -15` the `tomcat` process)

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference in behaviour if you use Tomcat's shutdown script or use kill -15. The end result is exactly the same - a clean shutdown. The only difference is a slight difference in the code path that starts the shutdown process.